# React toggle select field not removing when a specific checkbox is unchecked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, coffeescript

I am creating a form in React, there is an option where you can select a State (such as Alabama, Alaska, etc) if a specific select box is checked.

The issue I am having is when unchecking the box, the States select component is not removed.

```
Input = require('react-bootstrap').Input
States = require('./States.cjsx')

module.exports = InputForm = React.createClass(

propTypes:
  state_checkbox: React.PropTypes.bool

getInitialState: ->
{
  state_checkbox: false
}

toggleStatesField: ->
  console.log('Toggle state changed' + @refs.state_checkbox)
  @setState({ state_checkbox: @refs.state_checkbox })

showStatesField: ->
 if @refs.state_checkbox
   <States />
 else
   false

render: ->
  return(
   <Input type="checkbox" ref="state_checkbox" label="Import State?" onChange={@toggleStatesField} value={@state.state_checkbox} />
      { @showStatesField() }
  )
 )
```

In the react dev extension, the initial state is set to `false`. When the item is toggled, it then shows `Input{...}` while the state in this object is `null`.

I believe the issue is that the `state_checkbox` returning an object, instead of a boolean. I have searched but cannot find a way to update the state in the `Input{...}` object with `@setState` or changing it to be a boolean with the `propTypes` above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `@refs.state_checkbox` to determine whether the `States` component should render, but this `ref` will always be truthy.  You probably meant to use `@state`.

```
toggleStatesField: ->
  console.log('Toggle state changed' + @refs.state_checkbox)
  @setState({ state_checkbox: @refs.state_checkbox.refs.input.checked })

showStatesField: ->
 if @state.state_checkbox
   <States />
 else
   false
```

Comment: Thanks Ben that solved my issue, can you elaborate on why I have to call the refs twice?

Comment: You're using `Input` from the `react-bootstrap` package, which hides the inner input element that is actually rendered to the DOM.  Because of this, we need to check the internal refs of `Input` to get the actual html input.